# Prediction Interval from Markov Chains

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, triangles, markov-chains

Thank you for taking the time to look at my question.

Short, less involved question: How do you find Prediction Intervals with non-Gaussian residuals?

Here is the situation: I have made a model that predicts a student's grades at the twelve week mark using a discrete time Markov Chain. It uses an empirically constructed stochastic matrix of 80 transition observations. It takes the dot product of the estimated probability vector, P[12], and the percentages associated with each grade to return a scalar percentage estimate.

When testing the model against unused data, I found the residuals to be heavily skewed. They appeared to fit a triangular distribution much more than a normal distribution, using the Freedman-Diaconis method for bins. I also verified this with Anderson-Darling and Kolmogorov-Smirnov tests.

I have only read methods for constructing prediction intervals (what I planned to use to account for the prediction error) with normally distributed residuals. What are alternative methods of constructing prediction intervals for non-Guassian residuals? I am currently using:

Lower Bound: $$Predicted Value - RMSD\left| a + {\sqrt \frac {\alpha (b-a)(c-a)}{2}} \right|$$

Upper Bound: $$Predicted Value + RMSD\left| b + {\sqrt \frac {\alpha (b-a)(b-c)}{2}} \right|$$

The terms to the right of the +/- are the critical values for a triangular distribution with error $\alpha$, min = a, max = b, mode = c where a, b $\neq$ c. I'm positive there are better methods, that account for the variance of the residuals and degrees of freedom.

Also, if anyone can recommend statistic textbooks or articles that emphasize/teach inference without the normality assumption, I'd really appreciate that!

Comment: This seems roughly analogous to the notion of *bias* in statistical estimators.

Comment: @hardmath, I had considered that, which made me consider turning this into a linear model. It seems there's a lot more "support" for sort of that framing. For example, for a 2x2 matrix A made of vectors - **a** and **b** - would yield:

[**a** **b**].P[x] dot G (the grade percentages). I would get the equation:

(a1+a2+a3)*_p1_*g1+.(b1+b2+b3)*_p2_*_g2_

Then, I could use the typical formulas E[a1+a2+a3] = E[a1]+E[a2]+E[a3] etc, but in this case, I don't feel I have the data to make inferences on 121 random variables (the coefficients).

Comment: For inference without normality (i.e., non-classical inference), look into Bayesian or Likelihood inference. Here's an example for Bayes: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0470141158/ref=pd_lpo_sbs_dp_ss_3?pf_rd_p=1944687702&pf_rd_s=lpo-top-stripe-1&pf_rd_t=201&pf_rd_i=0964793849&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_r=1WQ7FPBQC7VA6YARXFR6. For likelihood inference, try "In All LIkelihood" by Yudi Pawitan.

Comment: Maybe start with the Wikipedia article on [non-parametric statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonparametric_statistics).  Related search terms are "distribution free methods" and "robust statistics".  The issue of whether you have enough observations to estimate $121$ parameters (as the transition probabilities) is another matter.  As I'm sure you are keenly aware, your Question could be improved by trimming it down to something that can be addressed in a relatively brief Answer, using reasoned mathematical arguments.

Comment: Thank you for the recommendation, @Bey. All the statistics courses I've taken (undergraduate) focus on classical inference and include maybe 1 chapter of non-parametric methods. These should help.

Comment: @hardmath, I've edited the question for concision and included my initial solution to this issue. Could you comment on the validity or if I can improve it more?